# How to fetch a set of records from a table given their start and end-points in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 Table structures :

```
TAB_1 ( TRN_ID , STN_CODE,DIST_FRM_SRC)    

TAB_2 ( TRN_ID , SRC_STN , DSTN_STN )
```

Data in TAB_1 :

[image]

Data in TAB_2

[image]

I have to fetch all the rows from TAB_1 Corresponding to SRC_STN and DST_STN in TAB_2 , So OP will be

[image]

Please guide .

Comment: You should have integer STN_CODE's...

Comment: Note that `s11 < s2`... You really need to extract the integer part from the STN_CODE and compare the integer values - not the strings - to get the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple join:

```
SQL> with
  2  tab_1 (trn_id, stn_code, dist_frm_src) as
  3    (select 100, 'GHU', 0 from dual union all
  4     select 100, 'SDP', 2 from dual union all
  5     select 100, 'DRK', 5 from dual union all
  6     select 100, 'SAB', 7 from dual union all
  7     select 100, 'DRT', 8 from dual union all
  8     select 100, 'POL', 10 from dual union all
  9     select 100, 'WRT', 15 from dual),
 10  tab_2 (trn_id, src_stn, dstn_stn) as
 11    (select 100, 'SDP', 'POL' from dual),
 12  --
 13  dfs as
 14    (select x.trn_id,
 15            a.dist_frm_src val_1,
 16            b.dist_frm_src val_2
 17     from tab_2 x join tab_1 a on x.trn_id = a.trn_id and x.src_stn = a.stn_code
 18                  join tab_1 b on x.trn_id = b.trn_id and x.dstn_stn = b.stn_code
 19    )
 20  select a.trn_id, a.stn_code, a.dist_frm_src
 21  from tab_1 a join dfs d on a.trn_id = d.trn_id
 22                         and a.dist_frm_src between d.val_1 and d.val_2
 23  order by trn_id, a.dist_frm_src;

    TRN_ID STN DIST_FRM_SRC
---------- --- ------------
       100 SDP            2
       100 DRK            5
       100 SAB            7
       100 DRT            8
       100 POL           10

SQL>
```

Comment: @Littlefoot ,Sir , but S1 is a varchar type value , how can between work on it ? In real scenario I will have complete string values so between can't work on a value like KYZ or PTJ

Comment: I can't know your "real scenario" unless you say so. KYZ is different from S2, so - all we can do is *guess*. Do these values contains only letters, letters and numbers, only numbers, which combinations of letters and numbers, any special characters, ... too many unknown situations.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out (too late, sorry). I updated my answer. Have a look, please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the **integer part** from the station codes which are **VARCHAR2** data type, and then get the data between the integers.

Since station codes has `S` prefix, I've used **LTRIM** to trim it and convert the string into number using **TO_NUMBER**:

```
SELECT
    t1.trn_id, t1.stn_code, t1.dist_frm_src
FROM
    tab_1   t1
    JOIN tab_2   t2 
    ON t1.trn_id = t2.trn_id
WHERE
    to_number(ltrim(t1.stn_code, 'S'))
    BETWEEN to_number(ltrim(t1.src_stn, 'S')) 
    AND     to_number(ltrim(t1.dstn_stn, 'S'))
ORDER BY t1.trn_id, t1.stn_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `join`:

```
select t1.*
from tab_1 t1
inner join tab_2 t2 
    on t1.trnid = t2.trnid and t1.stn_code between t2.src_stn and t2.dstn_stn
```

Another option uses `not exists`; this is handy if there may be overlaping intervals in `tab_2`:

```
select t1.*
from tab_1 t1
where exists (
    select 1 
    from tab_2 t2 
    where t1.trnid = t2.trnid and t1.stn_code between t2.src_stn and t2.dstn_stn
)
```

Comment: Sir , but S1 is a varchar type value , how can between work on it ? In real scenario I will have complete string values so between can't work on a value like KYZ or PTJ

Comment: @radha: between does support string comparisons. Stringwise, `'S2'` isi between `'S1'` and `'S5`', so this works for your sample data. If you have more complex cases, you should show them in your data, and explain how you want to handle them...

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple join *with* window functions:

```
select t12.TRN_ID, t12.STN_CODE, t12.DIST_FRM_SRC
from (select t2.*,
             min(case when t1.stn_code = t2.src_stn then dist_frm_src end) as first_dist_frm_src,
             max(case when t1.stn_code = t2.dst_stn then dist_frm_src end) as last_dist_frm_src
      from tab_1 t1 join
           tab_2 t2
           on t1.trn_id = t2.trn_id
     ) t12
where t12.dist_fm_src between first_dist_frm_src and last_dist_frm_src;
```